# Can't get a descending sorted list. Its sorting for positive number but not for negative numbers. Why? Please see output below. Python version 3.9.7

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, max

This question is for my assignment so I can't use built-in function for max and sorting

myMax() returns the maximum number from a list and mySort() sorts in descending order

Input I am giving
Please enter a list of different numbers separated by ',' : 1,-3,4.5,5,18,-1,3,-4

```
def myMax(a_list):

    
    max_num=a_list[0]
    print(a_list)
    location=0
    counter=1
    list_size=len(a_list)
    while(counter<list_size):
        if(max_num<a_list[counter]):
            
            max_num=a_list[counter]
            
            location=counter+1

        counter+=1
        
    return max_num,location

def mySort(a_list):

   
    list_size=len(a_list)
    counter=0
    des_list=[]
    while(counter<list_size):
        max_num,location=myMax(a_list)
        des_list.append(max_num)
        a_list.pop(location-1)
        counter+=1
    return des_list



input_list= input("Please enter a list of different numbers separated by ',' : ")

input_list=input_list.split(",")

input_list=[int(i) for i in input_list]

print("The descending sorted list is {}.".format(mySort(input_list)))
```

### Input:
1,-3,4.5,5,18,-1,3,-4

Output I am getting:
The descending sorted list is [18, 5, 4.5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Output I am expecting:
The descending sorted list is [18, 5, 4.5, 3, 1,-1,-3,-4]

Comment: Hint: all the numbers that are wrong have something in common.  Look at `max_num`.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger and run your program step by step?